# Re initialize Intercom in Application

Tags: android, intercom

We have multiple workspaces in Intercom. In the application, we want to change workspaces, without restart application. The official documentation says to use: `Intercom.client().logout()` and then initialize Intercom again. But it does not work, and appKey and appId did not change. How can we do that?

Comment: Please provide the code

Comment: @Gourav which code do you want?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you did. What is the problem and what's wrong there.

Comment: @Gourav The problem was after `Intercom.client().logout()`  and                  `Intercom.initialize(application, "android_sdk-token", "appId")` Intercom did not use new apptoken and appid, and workspaces did not change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Intercom documentation, I suspect what you try to achieve is not be possible. The documentation of `logout` states it's only resetting the part about the user, not the full Intercom setup:

> Logout is used to clear all local caches and user data the Intercom SDK has created. Use this at a time when you wish to log a user out of your app or change a user.

At least in the public API, there is no "unregister" to undo the creation of the `Intercom` singleton instance done during the `initialize` call. The only other methods I can see is `registerForLaterInitialisation` but that sounds as if you still will only be able to afterwards `initialize` once.

If you are looking for a way to trigger an app restart to switch, I've found the [Phoenix Library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ProcessPhoenix) useful to triggering a restart after internal testing settings have changed. But of course, it depends on your requirements since you already mentioned that you would like to achieve the switch without a restart.

You could add your question to the [Intercom Forum](https://community.intercom.com), which seems to regularly get replies by their engineering team.